# Is it possible create a custom UTM zone?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to detect the CRS (coordinate reference system) of a layer, but it is between

```
WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N

and

WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N
```

In fact the definition shows srsName="GEOPOIUTM32.5" srsDimension="2"

But I can't find any SRS like this in QGIS.

Comment: @mkennedy I know how to create a custom UTM zone with integers, but I dont know if have any sense a zone and a half

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're getting at. To me, 32.5 means that the central meridian is halfway between 32's and 33's, thus, 12E with all other parameters remaining the same. I could be wrong though!

Comment: can you edit your question to include (a) your .prj file (if it's a shapefile) or the output from gdalinfo if it's a raster,  (b) the area you're looking at and (c) how old is the map. I found a possible match on [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org) but not sure unless you can post more info.

Comment: The zone number in `+proj=utm` surely works only for integer values, representing 6-degree-wide zones. But there have been 3-degree-wide transverse mercator projections in the past, like the German and Russian Gauss-Krueger system.

Answer (score 3):

32N: Central meridian 9

33N: Central meridian 15

32,5: Central meridian 12

Create a new CRS with these parameters

`+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=0.9996   +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80  +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0`

I found gml data [here](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiiqqyNjP7TAhUGOxQKHTPOCz4QFgg1MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpastebin.com%2FuuFfKn3N&usg=AFQjCNGIl-RGj4t3mvP9d3WnIyo3valdQw)

In QGIS with User define CRS it's look like:
[image]

Comment: Yes! Thanks @Mike. Yours CRS definition works perfectly!