# Working in area with two different coordinate reference systems

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3

I am working in an area which is laying in both CRS (WGS84/UTM-Zone 32 : EPSG 32632) and (WGS84/UTM-Zone 33 : EPSG 32633). I would like that the conversion from geographical coordinates WGS84 (EPSG=4326) to projected metric coordinates should be in a single reference in plotting maps, in (UTM) system with central Meridian set at 12°.
Is it possible to customize this coordinate system in QGIS and what should be its WKT or Proj4?

Comment: There are literally an infinite number of spatial references that could meet your criteria, if you didn't insist on UTM (which is singularly unsuited to the task).

Answer (score 3):

You can shift the meridian to 12 degrees. The Proj string would looks like

`+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=0.9996   +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80  +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0`

See: [Is it possible create a custom UTM zone?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241095/is-it-possible-create-a-custom-utm-zone/241113)

But ask youself if you *really* want to do that vs using a pre-defined projection with an ESPG code. You can really go down the rabbit hole here if you aren't careful.

Comment: In fact, in the literature I found an example of a point in geographic system WGS84 (X_4326= 12.0809° & Y_4326=37.2733°) and its transformation to UTM system with central Meridian set at 12° (Easting=3007177 & Northing= 4126843).
I tried many attempts to change the parameters of the Proj4 of CRS, but without success. We notice that the Easting includes 7 numbers (which normally it should be 6 numbers in UTM) so perhaps there is a great slipping in some parameters.
Any help is welcome.